# 無投票なのにエラーページが表示されない

Tags: python, django

**前提・実現したいこと**
Djangoのチュートリアルに取り組んでいます。投票アプリケーションを作成するために以下のサイトを参照しています。

https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/4.0/intro/tutorial04/

無投票の場合にはエラーページが表示されるはずなのですが表示されません。

**該当のソースコード**
polls/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Choice, Question

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

polls/template/polls/index.html

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

polls/template/polls/detail.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

polls/template/polls/results.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

Comment: 最初の質問にコメントしたのと同様に、いずれにしろどこかで手順を抜かしたりミスしたり、何かの入力間違い等があるものと思われます。あるいは「こうなるはず」というのが何かの思い込みかもしれません。Tutorialの内容に沿ってキチンと作業しているかどうかは、今のところ貴方にしか確認できません。参照先ページの中にはいくつもの手順が書かれており、作業・確認対象も複数あります。どの段階まで進んだか、何と何のファイルを編集してその結果はどうなっているか、といったことの全てが詳細に記述されていないと、他の人には検証することが出来ません。

Comment: Tutorialの「やってみた」経緯をブログ記事にしているのを見つけた(Djangoの版数は少し古いようですが)ので、これと比較してみてはどうでしょう？ [5. はじめての Django アプリ作成、その 4 - Django公式サイトのチュートリアルを咀嚼しながらやってみる](https://www.icoro.com/2021052511846/5) あるいはもっと古い版数のDjango用記事ですがエラーがどうとかの記述があるので参考になるかも。[Python Django チュートリアル(4)](https://qiita.com/maisuto/items/fef306bafc57f218794d) あとはこんなQ&A記事もあります。[ｄｊａｎｇｏチュートリアル４項目の汎用ビューについて](https://teratail.com/questions/230951)

Comment: 教えて頂いたサイトを参考に再度やり直したのですが、変わらず無投票でのエラーが表示されないのと、新たに投票後のサイトが表示されなくなりました。

Comment: Tutorialの何処まで実行した時なのか、Tutorialにはどういうエラーが表示されると書いてある(あるいは詳細は書いていない？)がどんな状態になるのか、とかも書いてみてください。あと前回の質問のように、途中まで実行して上手くいかなくて質問した状態から何か対処を行ったことで、最初から順番に実行するのとは変わってしまったといった状態があるのかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

とりあえず以下のようなものでしょうか、作業漏れと古い記事をコピペした結果のようですね。
こうしたちょっとした漏れやミスが問題につながりますので、よくチェックするようにしてください。

---

polls/views.py:最初の行の import が不足しています。
誤：

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

正：

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
```

---

polls/template/polls/index.html:Tutorialの前のページでの入力に不足(`{% endfor %}`)があります。
誤：

```
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    </ul>
```

正：

```
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

---

polls/template/polls/detail.html:コメントで紹介した古い版のTutorialで作業した記事の内容が使われています。
誤：

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

正：

```
<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<fieldset>
    <legend><h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1></legend>
    {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
    {% endfor %}
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

Comment: 訂正ありがとうございます。しかし、投票後のサイトは表示されたのですが、無投票でのエラーサイトは表示されませんでした。kunif様の方では表示されたのでしょうか？

Comment: ページが遷移するのではなく、同じページのラジオボタンの上に`You didn't select a choice.`と太字で表示されるました。それがエラーメッセージ扱いだと思われます。

Comment: 古いバージョンのように、エラーサイトが表示されるものだと思っていました。無事、ラジオボタンの上にYou didn't select a choice.と太字で表示されるました。ありがとうございました。